# Mapping search results in rails when working with Association

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, search, mapping, sunspot-rails

I have a two models as:

```
Product { has_may variants}


Variant {belongs to product}
```

I used Sunspot search, and in result I retrieved selected variants, now I want this result as my search result contains the each Product who's one or more variant is retrieved by the search.

code sample of search is as follows:

```
@search = Sunspot.search(Spree::Variant) do
  keywords params[:keywords]      
  with :is_active, true  
  with  :deleted_at,nil
  if params[:ah].present? && params[:al].present?
    (Date.parse(params[:al])..Date.parse(params[:ah])).each do |d|
    with :f2r_available_on, d.to_time
    end
  end
end
@products = @search.results
```

Answer (score 0):

Let me first clarify: in your code above, `@search.results` is an array of variant records returned from your search, and you want to get all products associated with one or more of these variants?

If so, then this should do that:

```
@products = Product.where(:id => @search.results.map(&:product_id))
```

Comment: it gives me error as :
uninitialized constant Spree::ProductsController::Product

Comment: What is your `product` model called? Perhaps `Spree::Product`? If so, then: `@products = Spree::Product.where(:id => @serach.results.map(&:product_id))`.